# Getting TypeError: must be str, not list when trying to converse with a Chatbot you can find a code below

Tags: python, python-3.x, chatbot

Created this simple chatbot but immediately when I started conversing it throws an error, can anbody please explain why I'm getting the error?

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot(['hi! there!',
                  'hi!',
                  'how do you do?',
                  'i\'m cool',
                  'fine, you?',
                  'always cool',
                  'i\m ok',
                  'glad to hear that',
                  'i feel awesome',
                  'excellent, glad to hear that',
                  'not so good',
                  'what\'s your name?'])

list_trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)
'''
while True:
   request = input('You: ')
   response = chatbot.get_response(request)
   print('Bot: ',response)
'''
```

This is the error message:

```
You: how are you?

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
         <ipython-input-30-31083fafbef3> in <module>()
         1 while True:
         2   request = input('You: ')
   ----> 3   response = chatbot.get_response(request)
         4   print('Bot: ',response)


    TypeError: must be str, not list
''''''''''''''''
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: @Shivam Did the error message have any additional information? When I run your code with ChatterBot 1.0.4, I also get a TypeError, and near the end of the traceback it says it is because of the code  `persona='bot:' + self.name` within ChatterBot. The errror message is confusing, but it probably means that the bot name hasn't been set correctly (you are initialising the `ChatBot` name with a list rather than a string)

Answer (score 0):

From the [Chatterbot quickstart](https://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) documentation, it looks like `ChatBot` expects the name of the bot (a string) rather than a list. You can provide the conversation list later in the train step.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('Bot Name Here')

list_trainer = ListTrainer(chatbot)

list_trainer.train([
    'hi! there!',
    'hi!',
    'how do you do?',
    'i\'m cool',
    'fine, you?',
    'always cool',
    'i\m ok',
    'glad to hear that',
    'i feel awesome',
    'excellent, glad to hear that',
    'not so good',
    'what\'s your name?'])

# Check that the bot name has been set correctly
print('bot name:', chatbot.name)
assert isinstance(chatbot.name, str), "Chatbot name needs to be a string!"

response = chatbot.get_response("how do you do?")
print(response)
```

Comment: tried adding the name still I'm getting the same error

Comment: @Shivam Would you be able to check that the chatbot name has set correctly? Try adding `print('bot name:', chatbot.name)` just before `chatbot.get_response` to check that the name is what you expect.